# Get Multiple Connection Properties Using VBA in different cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which runs through the folder to get "Connection Name", "Command Text", and "Connection String".
My code runs through the folder and gets all "connection name in Excel" but prints only one "Command String".
Could anyone help me out to get all the connection strings in

```
Private oFSO As Object ' For FileSystemObject

Private oRng As Range, N As Long ' Range object and Counter

 

Sub Main()

    Dim sRootFDR As String 'Root folder

    Dim FILE_FILTER As String

    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   

    'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User

    Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

 

        With FldrPicker

            .Title = "Select A Target Folder"

            .AllowMultiSelect = False

                 If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode

            sRootFDR = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"

        End With

 

    'In Case of Cancel

NextCode:

    sRootFDR = sRootFDR

    If sRootFDR = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

 

    'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")

     FILE_FILTER = "*.xl*"

   

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    N = 0

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        .UsedRange.ClearContents ' Remove previous contents

        .Range("A1:E1").Value = Array("Filename", "Connections", "Connection Name", "Connection String", "Command Text")

        .Range("A1:E1").Font.Bold = True

        .Range("A1:E1").EntireColumn.AutoFit

        .Range("A1:E1").EntireRow.AutoFit

        Set oRng = .Range("A2") ' Initial Cell to start storing results

    End With

    ListFolder sRootFDR

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set oRng = Nothing

    Set oFSO = Nothing

    MsgBox N & " Excel files has been checked for connections."

   

ResetSettings:

  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

 

Private Sub ListFolder(ByVal sFDR As String)

    Dim oFDR As Object

    ' List the files of this Directory

    ListFiles sFDR, FILE_FILTER

    ' Recurse into each Sub Folder

    For Each oFDR In oFSO.GetFolder(sFDR).SubFolders

        ListFolder oFDR.Path & "\" ' Need '\' to ensure the file filter works

    Next

    oRng.Offset(0, 0).EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub

 

Private Sub ListFiles(ByVal sFDR As String, ByVal sFilter As String)

    Dim sItem As String

    sItem = Dir(sFDR & sFilter)

    Do Until sItem = ""

        N = N + 1 ' Increment Counter

        oRng.Value = sFDR & sItem

        CheckFileConnections oRng.Value ' Call Sub to Check the Connection settings

        Set oRng = oRng.Offset(1) ' Move Range object to next cell below

        sItem = Dir

    Loop

End Sub

 

Private Sub CheckFileConnections(ByVal sFile As String)

    Dim oWB As Workbook, oConn As WorkbookConnection

    Dim sConn As String, sCMD As String

    'Alter

    Dim sName As String

    Application.StatusBar = "Opening workbook: " & sFile

    Set oWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFile, ReadOnly:=True)

    Debug.Print sFile

    With oWB

        oRng.Offset(0, 1).Value = .Connections.Count ' 1 column to right (B)

        For Each oConn In .Connections

            On Error Resume Next

            If Len(sConn) > 0 Then sConn = sConn & vbLf

            If Len(sCMD) > 0 Then sCMD = sCMD & vbLf

            If Len(sCMD) > 0 Then sName = sName & vbLf

            sConn = sConn & oConn.OLEDBConnection.Connection 'Connecting String

            sCMD = sCMD & oConn.OLEDBConnection.CommandText 'Command Text

            sName = sName & oConn.Name 'Connection Name

            'Debug.Print sName

        Next

        'Write data to excel

        oRng.Offset(0, 2).Value = sName

        oRng.Offset(0, 3).Value = sConn

        oRng.Offset(0, 4).Value = sCMD

       

    End With

    oWB.Close False ' Close without saving

    Set oWB = Nothing

    Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```

I need result like in the image when I loop through the folder having 13 COnnection Name and 13 Connection Strings and Command Text.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I see a not initialized variable 'FILE_FILTER' in a following code. Most probably this is a problem.

```
Private Sub ListFolder(ByVal sFDR As String)
Dim oFDR As Object
    
    ' FILE_FILTER seems is always empty
    Call ListFiles(sFDR, FILE_FILTER)  
   
    For Each oFDR In oFSO.GetFolder(sFDR).SubFolders
        ListFolder oFDR.Path & "\"
    Next
    oRng.Offset(0, 0).EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Then, it's better to have an 'Option Explicit' declaration, it helps a lot.
When you call a function or sub it is more clear when you use the 'Call' statment
Then, try not to use GOTO exept "On Error GOTO ErrHandler". GOTO makes code more difficult for reading.
I just refactored your code a little bit, so, you can see how to avoid GOTO.
And use Wathches/Locals/Immediate as hell ).

```
Option Explicit

Private oFSO As Object ' For FileSystemObject
Private oRng As Range, N As Long ' Range object and Counter

Sub Main()
Dim sRootFDR As String 'Root folder
Dim FILE_FILTER As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With FldrPicker
        .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

             If Not (.Show <> -1) Then 'GoTo NextCode '!!!!!
                sRootFDR = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
            End If
    End With
'In Case of Cancel
'NextCode: '!!!!!
'!!!!!
'sRootFDR = sRootFDR '!!!!! useless code

If Not (sRootFDR = "") Then 'GoTo ResetSettings '!!!!!
'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
    FILE_FILTER = "*.xl*"
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    N = 0
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .UsedRange.ClearContents ' Remove previous contents
        .Range("A1:E1").Value = Array("Filename", "Connections", "Connection Name", "Connection String", "Command Text")
        .Range("A1:E1").Font.Bold = True
        .Range("A1:E1").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .Range("A1:E1").EntireRow.AutoFit
        Set oRng = .Range("A2") ' Initial Cell to start storing results
    End With
    Call ListFolder (sRootFDR)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set oRng = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    MsgBox N & " Excel files has been checked for connections."
End If
'ResetSettings:

'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub ListFolder(ByVal sFDR As String)
Dim oFDR As Object
    ' List the files of this Directory
    Call ListFiles(sFDR, FILE_FILTER)  '!!!!! FILE_FILTER is not declared
    ' Recurse into each Sub Folder
    For Each oFDR In oFSO.GetFolder(sFDR).SubFolders
        Call ListFolder (oFDR.Path & "\") ' Need '\' to ensure the file filter works
    Next
    oRng.Offset(0, 0).EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub

Private Sub ListFiles(ByVal sFDR As String, ByVal sFilter As String)
Dim sItem As String
    sItem = Dir(sFDR & sFilter)
    Do Until sItem = ""
        N = N + 1 ' Increment Counter
        oRng.Value = sFDR & sItem
        CheckFileConnections oRng.Value ' Call Sub to Check the Connection settings
        Set oRng = oRng.Offset(1) ' Move Range object to next cell below
        sItem = Dir
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub CheckFileConnections(ByVal sFile As String)
Dim oWB As Workbook, oConn As WorkbookConnection
Dim sConn As String, sCMD As String
'Alter
Dim sName As String
    Application.StatusBar = "Opening workbook: " & sFile
    Set oWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFile, ReadOnly:=True)
    Debug.Print sFile
    With oWB
        oRng.Offset(0, 1).Value = .Connections.Count ' 1 column to right (B)
        For Each oConn In .Connections
            On Error Resume Next
            If Len(sConn) > 0 Then sConn = sConn & vbLf
            If Len(sCMD) > 0 Then sCMD = sCMD & vbLf
            If Len(sCMD) > 0 Then sName = sName & vbLf
            sConn = sConn & oConn.OLEDBConnection.Connection 'Connecting String
            sCMD = sCMD & oConn.OLEDBConnection.CommandText 'Command Text
            sName = sName & oConn.Name 'Connection Name
            'Debug.Print sName
        Next
    
        'Write data to excel
    
        oRng.Offset(0, 2).Value = sName
        oRng.Offset(0, 3).Value = sConn
        oRng.Offset(0, 4).Value = sCMD
    End With
    
    oWB.Close False ' Close without saving
    Set oWB = Nothing
    
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub '
```

Comment: It is throwing an error.""

Comment: when? where? Err.Description? Can you specify the row with error?

Comment: Variable Not defined. Error at "FILE_FILTER"